# AngularJS $location.path('/') does not clear search() parameters

Tags: angularjs

I am using

```
$location.path('/login');
```

to redirect back to a login page if a user is not logged in, or in general use this to redirect anywhere. But If I already have an url that looks like this

`/register/final-step?token=mF6xY2cQvB9Vccb0J1l5uTu4H10lWkkf`

and redirect to

`$location.path('/');`

then the search parameters do not get cleared, so I get an url like this

`/?token=mF6xY2cQvB9Vccb0J1l5uTu4H10lWkkf`

Even if I use UI-Router's

```
$state.go('home');
```

the

`?token=mF6xY2cQvB9Vccb0J1l5uTu4H10lWkkf`

part is still there.

I don't understand. Do I really have to clear parameters manually this every time I need to go to another state or url? This does not seem very
legit to me. What do I do wrong? I don't want to do `window.location.href` because that makes a full page reload which is not something I want to do.

What should I do to clear the parameters? I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: What does the *"home"* state URL look like?

Comment: Oddly, I've found the opposite. When I transition to a new state, query parameters are cleared

Comment: what about when you are using $location? is it the same?

Comment: I don't use `$location` to change states

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The part of the url after the `?` is called the `search` (in angular -- in other things it may be referred to as the `query`).  You were dealing with only the `path`, which is the part before the `?`.

You can use it like this (and yes, it's used for way more than just searches...but that's its name in this context).

```
// Get the current value
var curr_search = $location.search();

// Clear the current search
$location.search({});

// Set the current search values
$location.search({key: "value"});
```

Comment: No problem!  Figuring out how to clear it was what I looked up recently that had this all fresh in my mind.

Comment: Thanks for this! I started stepping through the $compose function and was wondering where an errant parameter was coming from. This helped a ton.

Comment: @LocalTrav Please try reading the answer again.  It answers the question exactly, including why setting the path does not clear the search.